# TextFlow getPrefWidth returning -1

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get the width and height of a TextFlow after the Text objects have been added to it

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package newcodeeditor;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Arhowk
 */
public class Tester extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextFlow t = new TextFlow();
        Text t1 = new Text("test\n");


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(t);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println(t.getPrefWidth());
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

but this keeps returning -1. (so do min and max width)

How am i supposed to get the width/height of the flow object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
double w = textFlow.prefWidth(-1);
```

to compute the preferred width, then

```
double h = textFlow.prefHeight(w);
```

to compute the preferred height.

The `getPrefWidth()` method just returns the value of the user-settable `prefWidth` property, which by default is `-1`, meaning "use computed size".

Btw, in the code you posted, no `Text` node is added to the `TextFlow`.

Comment: Oh, I suppose it should have atleast 1 Text node! I was just using that code to post here, the actual code I had problems with was integrated into a much larger project.